# Insert New Entries into last JSON item

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON structure that looks like this

```
{ 
"messages":[ 
    { 
        text: 'Some text' 
    },
    {   
        text: 'Some text again' 
    },
    { 
        text: 'Some text again again' 
    } 
 ]
}
```

I will like to insert a new object into the last `text` object so that the structure now looks like this

```
    "messages":[ 
    { 
        text: 'Some text' 
    },
    {   
        text: 'Some text again' 
    },
    { 
        text: 'Some text again again', 
        "quick_replies": [
            {
                "title":"Loved it!",
                "block_names": ["Block 1"]
            },
            {
                "title":"test",
                "block_names": ["Block 1"]
            }
        ]
    } 
]
}
```

I was trying to use `message[0].text.text.text = quick_replies...` however I don't think that solution will work as the `,` would be missing and would cause an error.

How can I insert the new data into the JSON structure?

Comment: is this suppose to be object or json ? what i can see is JSON, and you said that ' new object into the last'

Comment: @Gagantous It's not JSON, but js object.

Comment: @alexmac Javascipt object ?

Comment: @Gagantous yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the last message, use `length - 1`:

```
myObj.messages[myObj.messages.length - 1].quick_replies = [
        {
            "title":"Loved it!",
            "block_names": ["Block 1"]
        },
        {
            "title":"test",
            "block_names": ["Block 1"]
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the structure you have

```
{ 
  messages:[ 
    { 
        text: 'Some text', 
    },
    {   
        text: 'Some text again',
    },
    { 
        text: 'Some text again again', 
    }, 
  ],
}
```

To edit the last item :

```
messages[messages.length - 1].quick_replies = ...
```

---

Here we gonna get the size of the array, which is `3`, subtract `1` and access the element in the array.

Why do we substract `1`? Because an array begins at index `0` and not `1`.

Answer (score -3):

Use the Push method:

```
var js = { 
"messages":[ 
    { 
        text: 'Some text' 
    },
    {   
        text: 'Some text again' 
    },
    { 
        text: 'Some text again again' 
    } 
 ]
};

js.messages.push({ 
        text: 'Some text again again', 
        "quick_replies": [
            {
                "title":"Loved it!",
                "block_names": ["Block 1"]
            },
            {
                "title":"test",
                "block_names": ["Block 1"]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: this adds an item to the array the OP wants to modify the last item in the array